# Recently visited directories?

Tags: windows

Does Windows store a list of recently-visited directories somewhere in the registry, or in Docs & Settings?

Comment: Is your problem specific to a version of Windows?

Comment: Why do you cross-post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699361/most-recently-used-directories

Comment: ...because people don't read the FAQs and the folks at SO tend to comment like "you should ask your question here www.superuser.com" rather than "you should have asked .. it will be moved"... :-( (It's a multipost by the way; much worse than an old school crosspost.)

Answer (score 2):

Windows Explorer does keep such a list in the registry, if not turned off.

The article [How to Remove Unwanted Items from Addressbar History in Windows Explorer?](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-remove-unwanted-items-from-addressbar-history-in-windows-explorer/) shows how to access this list stored in

> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\TypedPaths`

Windows keeps lots of lists about your activities. If you're concerned about it, here's a commercial product that cleans up everything: [Clear All History](http://www.clearallhistory.com/). Its following screenshot might serve as a demonstration of which history is kept about your actions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows XP:

1. The %USERPROFILE%\Recent\ folder, where %USERPROFILE% is something like "C:\Documents and Settings\yourname". This folder contains shortcuts of recently visited files.
2. This registry entry contains the ordered file list:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\OpenSaveMRU
```

Not sure about Windows Vista and Windows 7, but they should be the same.