# Can Windows XP show me list of recently visited folders (using Windows Explorer)?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

Can Windows XP show me list of recently visited folders (using Windows Explorer)? I have seen solutions for Windows Vista/7 or solutions incorporating Internet Explorer, but I wanted something when using the standard Windows Explorer.

[This is a useful article but only really gives a solutions in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/67806/recently-visited-directories)

I did have a small third party piece of software before years ago for this purpose but I couldn't find it again. Is this somewhere lurking in Windows XP by default or something a small third party application can show me?

Comment: The bottom anwser on that question you linked to is specifically for Windows XP?

Comment: This is true so my wording is slightly wrong maybe but this is for ' recently visited files' as opposed to folders/directories =(

Comment: Oh right! Got it!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Filebox eXtender](http://www.hyperionics.com/files/index.asp). Works with open/save dialog box too and also has a nifty favorites button.